# Disable Alt + F1 keyboard shortcut in Cinnamon

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, cinnamon

I am running Linux Mint 14 with Cinnamon. Currently <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> opens the 'Expo' mode, showing all workspaces.

I would simply like to unbind/disable this shortcut. Where can I do this? I have searched through the standard keyboard shortcuts in the Cinnamon settings as well as in gconf-editor, to no avail.

Comment: With Cinnamon 2.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 the solutions posted so far do not work.
In the settings under Keyboard Shortcuts > Cinnamon > Toggle Expo all bindings are "unassigned".
In gsettings/gconf-editor I have set all occurrences of "panel-main-menu" to "[]". No value at all exists for "<Alt>F1".
What the heck? I have been using this shortcut on each working day in the last ten years many times a day!

Answer (score 5):

To free Alt+F1 run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "[]"
```

To revert back run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['<Alt>F1']"
```

A logout might be necessary to activate these settings...

I got these from a colleague, whose source was [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126817/how-to-disable-alt-f1-alt-f2-shortcuts). He adds: "This is for Gnome3 but also applies to Muffin (Cinnamon's window manager) as it is a fork of Mutter (Gnome3's window manager)."

Comment: I prefer this approach, but it fails for linux mint 17 cinnamon.
I can execute the command and confirm that the value is changed: 
`/home/kidmose $ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu` produces `@as []` but keybind is still effective after reboot. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed! 
`sudo gsettings set org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings panel-main-menu []` and relogging worked for me. 
It seems like my issue was that the window manager, the structure in the GSettings or something else changed.

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux Mint 16 "Petra" Cinnamon, I had a similar problem.
Removing the Keyboard shortcuts under `gnome-control-center` and `cinnamon-control-center` had no effect.
Solution that worked for me:

- run `dconf-editor`
- navigate to `org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings`
- for `panel-main-menu`, replace `['<Alt>F1']` with `[]`
- logout & login

(props to [Nick Fortescue @ Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/531874/disable-alt-f1-keyboard-shortcut-in-cinnamon) and [michael-schaller @ github](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/2539) )

Comment: Do you know when I can find Control+F2? I want to remove it too. Thanks.

Comment: What is CTRL+F2? Did you mean ALT-F2?

Comment: no, I need to remove CTRL+F2 :)

Comment: what does CTRL-F2 do for you?

Comment: It opens the small window on the right with title "Enter a command to launch"

Comment: I figured out what is was - Cairo-Dock. Already disabled it on it's settings. Thank you!

Comment: The restart of muffin (logout/login) is critical, you can do it via alt-f2->r

Answer (score 3):

I have found very simple solution.

Just open `Settings > Keyboard`. Then select second control tab `Shortcuts` just below the window title of the keyboard dialog.

Then select from the left tree view select `General` root element. On the `Keyboard shortcuts` list the second option will be `Toggle Expo`. The second short cut is `Alt+F1` with me in the `Keyboard bindings` section. Just select and clear the shortcut sequence.

This way I am now able to use Alt+F1 freely in any application.

Summary: `Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> General -> Toggle Expo`

Comment: On recent systems, this it is called "Show the workspace selection screen"

Answer (score 1):

Above solutions worked for me for some time, but since last system upgrade (Arch linux), the `metacity` package has been replaced with `muffin` (if I undersetand correctly..), so if this stopped working for you too, try searching those keybindings inside path: `org.cinnamon.muffin.keybindings` instead of `org.gnome....`

Answer (score 1):

If you use last cinnamon and first answer does not help, go to

```
System settings -> keyboard -> keyboard shortcuts -> General -> "Toggle expo"
```

and disable it.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux Mint 20.1 you can make this option unassigned under: `keyboard -> shortcuts -> general -> show the workspace selection screen`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this via `gconf-editor`.

Look under `apps->metacity->global_keybindings`, [Metacity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Metacity) being the GTK2 Window Manager.  There should be an item `panel_main_menu`; double click to set its value to something other than `<Alt>F1` or leave it blank to remove the binding altogether.

(This works on Mint 13 with Cinnamon, I can only assume it'll work on Mint 14 as well.)