# Disable Control + F2 keyboard shortcut in Mint 16

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

There is [a similar topic](https://superuser.com/questions/531874/disable-alt-f1-keyboard-shortcut-in-cinnamon), but none of the solutions is working for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> combination.

I need to disable this shortcut in my Mint 16, any ideas?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? Gnome? Cinnamon? Mate? What does Ctrl+F2 do?

Comment: I figured out what it was. Cairo-Dock widget. I disabled it from it's own configuration. Thank you.

Comment: If you have time, please post your solution as an answer.